# QGIS - SpatiaLite triggers doesn't update properly each field

Tags: qgis, spatialite, sqlite, trigger

**See edit at the end of the post**

I am working in two layers:

> **HABITATS_POLY** (important fields: *"EUNIS_1" , "EUNIS_2" , "EUNIS_3" , "EUNIS_4"* ; *"EUNIS22_1" , "EUNIS22_2" , "EUNIS22_3" , "EUNIS22_4"*)

> **GESTION_CODES**  (important fields: *"EUNIS"*, *"EUNIS22"*

And one database:

> **BD_EUNIS22**

### First I update **HABITATS_POLY** by inserting or updating rows:

On [**HABITATS_POLY**]

INSERTION:

*[trigger's name: insert_eunis_gest]*

> Insertion of new rows in **HABITATS_POLY** when ("EUNIS_1" , "EUNIS_2"
> , "EUNIS_3" , "EUNIS_4") does not exists in **GESTION_CODES**
> ("EUNIS")

*[trigger's name: insert_eunis22_codes]*

> After insertion on **HABITATS_POLY** then UPDATE EUNIS22_1,
> EUNIS22_2, EUNIS22_3, EUNIS22_4 from EUNIS22 (**GESTION_CODES**) where
> EUNIS_1, EUNIS_2, EUNIS_3, EUNIS_4 (**HABITATS_POLY**) = EUNIS
> (**GESTION_CODES**)

### Which triggers insert/updates on **GESTION_CODES**

[**GESTION_CODES**]

INSERTION:

*[trigger's name: update_eunis22]*

> WHEN new EUNIS code is inserted in GESTION_CODES then update EUNIS22
> = Habitat EUNIS22 [On BD_EUNIS22 : Relation between Habitat EUNIS12 and EUNIS to get Habitat EUNIS22]

UPDATE:

*[trigger's name: update_eunis22_gest]*

> When EUNIS22 is updated then update fields "EUNIS22_1" , "EUNIS22_2"
> , "EUNIS22_3" , "EUNIS22_4" where EUNIS (**GESTION_CODES**) = EUNIS_1,
> EUNIS_2, EUNIS_3, EUNIS_4 (**HABITATS_POLY**)

### Which Reset "update" triggers on **HABITATS_POLY**

[**HABITATS_POLY**]

UPDATE:

*[trigger's name: update_eunis22_codes]*

> When EUNIS_1, EUNIS_2, EUNIS_3, EUNIS_4 is updated then update
> EUNIS22_1, EUNIS22_2, EUNIS22_3, EUNIS22_4 where EUNIS_1, EUNIS_2,
> EUNIS_3, EUNIS_4 (**HABITATS_POLY**) = EUNIS22 (**GESTION_CODES**)

I will not list the spoilers in this post to make it clearer, but will add them in the discussion.

My issue is that it is not working when I insert several polygons.
**In HABITATS_POLY, the update of EUNIS22 will be done on one occurrence of each code, but not on all the codes. So, as soon as the corresponding EUNIS22 or a EUNIS code is given, then if the other codes are identical, they will not be found.**

I'm working on it since weeks, there is always something wrong.

Here is a link to download an example project :[Test Project](https://fromsmash.com/Test-project-sqlitetriggers)

---

**EDIT:**

I am simplifying my question to address a specific issue that, once resolved, could help me understand the broader problem.

I want to update the fields EUNIS22_1, EUNIS22_2, EUNIS22_3, and EUNIS22_4 in the table HABITATS_POLY based on changes in the EUNIS22 field in the GESTION_CODE table. The current trigger is only updating one occurrence of each code.

When EUNIS22 is modified in the GESTION_CODES table, I aim to update all instances of codes EUNIS_1 (2, 3, or 4) in the HABITATS_POLY table where EUNIS_1 (2, 3, or 4) matches the EUNIS field in the GESTION_CODES table.

Ex:
[EUNIS22_1 = EUNIS22 where EUNIS_1 = EUNIS]

```
    CREATE TRIGGER D_rapat_eunis_to_eunis22_updt
AFTER UPDATE OF EUNIS22 ON GESTION_CODES
BEGIN
    UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
    SET "EUNIS22_1" = NEW.EUNIS22
    WHERE "EUNIS_1" = NEW.EUNIS;

    UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
    SET "EUNIS22_2" = NEW.EUNIS22
    WHERE "EUNIS_2" = NEW.EUNIS;

    UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
    SET "EUNIS22_3" = NEW.EUNIS22
    WHERE "EUNIS_3" = NEW.EUNIS;

    UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
    SET "EUNIS22_4" = NEW.EUNIS22
    WHERE "EUNIS_4" = NEW.EUNIS;
    END;
```

---

**EDIT2:**

The solution I might have found:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_eunis22_trigger
AFTER UPDATE OF EUNIS22 ON GESTION_CODES
BEGIN
    UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
    SET 
        "EUNIS22_1" = CASE WHEN "EUNIS_1" IN (SELECT "EUNIS" FROM GESTION_CODES) THEN (SELECT "EUNIS22" FROM GESTION_CODES WHERE "EUNIS" = "EUNIS_1") ELSE "EUNIS22_1" END,
        "EUNIS22_2" = CASE WHEN "EUNIS_2" IN (SELECT "EUNIS" FROM GESTION_CODES) THEN (SELECT "EUNIS22" FROM GESTION_CODES WHERE "EUNIS" = "EUNIS_2") ELSE "EUNIS22_2" END,
        "EUNIS22_3" = CASE WHEN "EUNIS_3" IN (SELECT "EUNIS" FROM GESTION_CODES) THEN (SELECT "EUNIS22" FROM GESTION_CODES WHERE "EUNIS" = "EUNIS_3") ELSE "EUNIS22_3" END,
        "EUNIS22_4" = CASE WHEN "EUNIS_4" IN (SELECT "EUNIS" FROM GESTION_CODES) THEN (SELECT "EUNIS22" FROM GESTION_CODES WHERE "EUNIS" = "EUNIS_4") ELSE "EUNIS22_4" END;
END;
```

---

**EDIT3:**

It is working, but the triggers seems not to apply to the last feature added, when I copy-paste several features at the same time.

Comment: I might have found a solution, by changing the way values are searched. 

I think this solution is slower.  See EDIT2

Comment: It is working, but the last row (or feature) is not updated when I copy-paste several features at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After carefully reanalyzing the process multiple times, I identified that the root cause of the issue stemmed from the order of trigger execution when the table is updated following a copy-paste operation. Specifically, the final row in HABITATS_POLY remained unaltered if the code in question had already undergone validation in the GESTION_CODES layer.

To address this, I implemented an additional trigger. The data undergoes scrutiny both after insertion and update in HABITATS_POLY and is reevaluated following an update in GESTION_CODES.

I improved a bit the code:

```
    CREATE TRIGGER G_rapat_eunis_to_eunis22_updt
AFTER UPDATE OF EUNIS22 ON GESTION_CODES
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE HABITATS_POLY
    SET 
        "EUNIS22_1" = CASE WHEN "EUNIS_1" IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE((SELECT "EUNIS22" FROM GESTION_CODES WHERE "EUNIS" = "EUNIS_1"), "-") END,
        "EUNIS22_2" = CASE WHEN "EUNIS_2" IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE((SELECT "EUNIS22" FROM GESTION_CODES WHERE "EUNIS" = "EUNIS_2"), "-") END,
        "EUNIS22_3" = CASE WHEN "EUNIS_3" IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE((SELECT "EUNIS22" FROM GESTION_CODES WHERE "EUNIS" = "EUNIS_3"), "-") END,
        "EUNIS22_4" = CASE WHEN "EUNIS_4" IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE((SELECT "EUNIS22" FROM GESTION_CODES WHERE "EUNIS" = "EUNIS_4"), "-") END;
END;
```

But now, the process is slower.